# CSS - display:inline breaks on IE - center aligning elements within jquery carousel

Tags: jquery, html, css

I had an issue getting my elements within a carousel to be center aligned if the number of elements did not fill the wrapper.  I managed to get this working by adding `display:inline` to the wrapper using JQuery if carousel does not scroll.  However this breaks in IE (version 11) and none of the elements show at all.  The weird thing is, if I select the ALT key, they display!

Can anyone explain this behaviour and suggest how I can fix this?  Please see this JSFIddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/bharatsing/ysuf1u1p/3/

```
.bxslider-inner {
    display: inline-block;
    float:none !important;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.bx-wrapper {
    max-width: 460px!important;
    text-align:center;
}

<ul class="bxslider">
  <li class="bxslider-inner"><div style="width:80px; height:80px; background:#CCC; padding:5px;">1</div></li>
 <li class="bxslider-inner"><div style="width:80px; height:80px; background:#F5F5F5; padding:5px;">2</div></li>
    <li class="bxslider-inner"><div style="width:80px; height:80px; background:#F5F5F5; padding:5px;">3</div></li>

</ul>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.bxslider').bxSlider({
    mode: 'horizontal',
    speed: 500,
    slideMargin:10,
    infiniteLoop: false,
    pager: false,
    controls: true,
    slideWidth: 80,
    minSlides: 1,
    maxSlides: 5,
    moveSlides: 1       });
    });

$(".bxslider").each(function(){
var nextDisabled = $(this).parents(".bx-wrapper:eq(0)").find(".bx-next").hasClass('disabled');
var prevDisabled = $(this).parents(".bx-wrapper:eq(0)").find(".bx-prev").hasClass('disabled');
    if(nextDisabled && prevDisabled)
  {
    $(this).css("display","inline");
  }
});
</script>
```

Comment: everything works fine on my end?

Comment: what version of ie?

Comment: really?  So you can see two rows of boxes in IE?  I only see 1 in IE and there should be 2.

Comment: My version of IE is 11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you cannot give a width to an inline element so ie is actually doing the right thing for once.

This means the `width:515%` is not respected so when the transform translate happens, the ul is moved off the screen.

Try this instead of the display inline:

```js
    $(this).css({
      "display":"inline-block",
      "width":"auto",
      "transform": "none"
    });
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ysuf1u1p/10/)